# What does the command "ifconfig <interface> 0.0.0.0" do?

Tags: linux, interface, ifconfig

The question is direct, what does the given command do, and what is it used for?

```
ifconfig <interface-name> 0.0.0.0
```

I know that 0.0.0.0 means all IP addresses on my local machine.

Also if I mess up an interface with this command, how do I reset it?

Comment: To those who would like to -1 this question, you may do so, but please tell me why you are doing it as well.

Comment: well u could try and read the manual first. # man ifconfig

Comment: It did not help.

Answer (score 5):

While this command usually assigns an IP to the interface, using `0.0.0.0` clears the primary IP of it. see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/153559/clear-ip-address-of-ethernet-interface) or [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Ethernet-Bridge-netfilter-HOWTO-3.html). Usually done to allow the ability to assign an IP via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

You have just given the  an invalid IP or a non-routable IP.
If you use a DHCP just issue,

```
dhclient <interface-name>
```

It will give you back your DHCP ip.

With a static Ip this should do it,

```
ifconfig <interface-name> < e.g. 192.168.1.125>
```

A `ifdown <interface-name>` and `ifup <interface-name>` should do it if you have manually configured the ip.